# How to see list of questions I have edited?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

One of the questions that I had edited few days ago was rejected by someone from SO site, and now I am not able to find what question was that I had edited. And so was wondering how to find the list of questions that I have edited in SO sites?

Comment: check your "Activity". Under "All Actions" there's "suggestions". That should do the trick

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Vogel612'sShadow for the help.

Comment: @Vogel612'sShadow (PSSST... why not write an answer?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Activity** tab, under **all actions** -> **suggestions** tab you can find all the approved, pending, rejected edits suggested by you.

Or you can use [the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) to navigate the tab directly.

```
https://<sitename>.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions
```